# Creating a data structure with 1 key, 2 values in C# and also retrieving values for a particular key

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures

I want to create a data structure with 1 key,2 values,which looks like this:

```
List<KeyValuePair<double, double, double>> list = new List<KeyValuePair<double, double, double>>();
```

I basically have x,y,z coordinate values and I want to keep on appending them in a data structure.After,appending the data,I would like to retrieve all the available "x"(something like "List").For each value of x,I want to find the multiple "y" values.And then for a particular "x" and "y" value,I would like to find all the multiple "z" values.

For e.g: if I have coordinates like (1,2,3) ; (1,3,4) ; (1,2,6); (1,2,9)
For a value of 1,I want to retrieve 2 and 3. Likewise,for a value of 1,2 ; I want to retrieve the values 6 and 9.

I would be really glad,if someone can let me know the procedure to do this in C#.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: As the name `KeyValuePair` says it's to store a Key and a Value. Here you have 3 value and no key a simple tuple is the datastructure you are looking for. this one is not.

Comment: Why not a `Dictionary<double, Tuple<double, double>>` or even `Dictionary<double, Dictionary<double, List<double>>>`?

Comment: Why do you want to use a Data structure at all, why not create a class (A DTO) that holds the data, and you can do what ever you want?

Comment: This sounds like you need a *multiple key* dictionary. Google for it, there are plenty of duplicates. @RaniDevpr, what has DTO to do with algorithm tag which imply performance of retrieving and efficiency of storing? Do you mean "use database to store them and run query to retrieve what you need"?

Comment: Use a proper class to hold your X/Y/Z values, it will make your code a lot more readable.

Comment: @DragandDrop just because a type contains the right number of properties of the right type doesn't mean it's a good fit. Especially not if it's not in mscorlib.

Comment: What about duplicates, shall they be removed? like (1,2,3); (1,2,4), shall it return for a query of 1: 2 and 2? or just 2?

Comment: I am not referring to any database! a DTO is not necessarily related to database, it is a transfer object between anything. basically, i meant to say create a regular class with needed properties. the answers using tuples are good, but that depends on how complicated things will be later, if this system is going to be more complicated then using a class is much cleaner and will make your life easier. however, if this is something not to be changed again and again, then tuples are good. regarding performance, talking about integers in memory it will not make huge difference.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!!

Comment: I would define a struct for coordinates if I had to deal with many of them. "double" is dangerous for == checks, should not be used for a dictionary ContainsKey like queries. I would prefer an [rtree](http://www.wikizero.org/index.php?q=aHR0cHM6Ly9lbi53aWtpcGVkaWEub3JnL3dpa2kvUi10cmVl) structure or something like that instead. But if your data and requirements are not that complicated, at least I would use an epsilon for equality checks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have unique keys and you have keys of varying width, so a dictionary nor a KeyValuePair are going to help you.

If, when looking up single values (the X of `(X, Y, Z)`), you are only interested in Y and never Z, you could pad the key with an unused value and store the records twice (so the key-value-pairs of `(1, 2, 3)` become `(0, 1, 2)` and `(1, 2, 3)`), but that won't really make things clearer.

You could store the records in a `List<Tuple<double, double, double>>`:

```
var list = new List<Tuple<double, double, double>>
{
    Tuple.Create<double, double, double>(1,2,3),
    Tuple.Create<double, double, double>(1,3,4),
    Tuple.Create<double, double, double>(1,2,6),
    Tuple.Create<double, double, double>(1,2,9),
};

var search = 1d;

var results = list.Where(t => t.Item1 == search)
                  .Select(t => t.Item2);
```

Then when you want to search on two values, utilize a tuple as well:

```
var search = Tuple.Create<double, double>(1, 2);

var results = list.Where(t => t.Item1 == search.Item1 && t.Item2 == search.Item2)
                  .Select(t => t.Item3);
```

Comment: @DragandDrop Which means importing a whole library for a simple 3 value class/struct? Overkill and potentially a misuse of that type.

Comment: @DavidG, I think that the name of op show that the real class could be usefull as it include vector and methode. Can be overkill I think it's worth mentionning.

Comment: @DragandDrop worth mentionning at least 4 time ! You made my day x)

Answer (score 0):

Basically the answer of CodeCaster, but with methods (I took the time creating it, but he was faster :))

```
public void TestMethod()
{
    List<Tuple<double, double, double>> list = new List<Tuple<double, double, double>>();
    list.Add(new Tuple<double, double, double>(1, 2, 3));
    list.Add(new Tuple<double, double, double>(1, 2, 5));
    list.Add(new Tuple<double, double, double>(8, 2, 3));
    list.Add(new Tuple<double, double, double>(1, 5, 3));

    var x = GetIt(1, list);
    var y = GetIt(1, 2, list);
}

public List<double> GetIt(double d, List<Tuple<double, double, double>> list)
{
    return (from a in list
            where a.Item1 == d
            select a.Item2).Distinct().ToList();
}

public List<double> GetIt(double d, double e, List<Tuple<double, double, double>> list)
{
    return (from a in list
            where a.Item1 == d && a.Item2 == e
            select a.Item3).Distinct().ToList();
}
```

Comment: The OP also wants a single value returned when searching on a single value.

Comment: `params double[]` ?

Comment: @CodeCaster: he wrote: "For a value of 1,I want to retrieve 2 and 3." So for me that results in a List

Comment: That's because their test data contains that. They say: _"For each value of x,I want to find the multiple "y" values [from (x, y, z)]."_

Comment: Ok, found another problem: duplicates!

Comment: Yeah, not specified in the question (examples given are both incorrect anyway), and I'll leave it up to the OP to find out about Distinct().

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple approachs to what you want. If you're using VS2017+, you could use Value Tuple (native when targetting .NET4.7, otherwise available in Nuget)

```
var list = new List<(double x, double y, double z)>();
list.Add((1,2,3));
list.Add((1,3,4));
list.Add((1,2,6));
list.Add((1,2,9));
```

And use Linq to group by x, y, and z.

To retrieve all y with x=1

```
var l1 = list.Where(i=>i.x==1).Select(i=>i.y);
```

To retrieve all z with x=1 and y=2

```
var l2 = list.Where(i=>i.x==1 && i.y==2).Select(i=>i.z);
```

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't recommend a Dictionary type approach because what you're trying to store are 3 values, not a key and a value.

I'd recommend the follow:

1. Create a class Coordinates
2. Make a list of said class
3. Use LINQ to go through it.

For example:

```
 public class Coordinates
{
    public float XCoord { get; set; }
    public float YCoor { get; set; }
    public float ZCoor { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can create a list and use LINQ to select the needed data, in this example I created a function that accepts X,Y, and Z to filter the list.

```
List<Coordinates> list = new List<Coordinates>(); //Populate the list
```

Then with the following method:

```
public List<Coordinates> SelectCoords(List<Coordinates> originalList, float? X, float? Y,float? Z)
    {
        List<Coordinates> filteredList = new List<Coordinates>(originalList);

        if (X != null)
        {
            filteredList = filteredList.Where(v => v.XCoord == X).ToList();
        }

        if (Y != null)
        {
            filteredList = filteredList.Where(v => v.YCoord == Y).ToList();
        }

        if (X != null)
        {
            filteredList = filteredList.Where(v => v.ZCoord == Z).ToList();
        }

        return filteredList;
    }
```

Lets you choose how to filter the list only returning the list with X,Y, and or Z

```
list = SelectCoords(list, 1, 2,null);
```

Answer (score -2):

Ms got your back and have a class for this just in case : [Point3D structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.media.media3d.point3d(v=vs.110).aspx).

Pros: It has a number of build in method that can be use full. And you can play around with point and vector.

Cons: It's overkill if you simply store those 3 double.

Comment: @CodeCaster, not enought time to edit code into answer I guess this is my bad. As this answer answer a part of the question. It will stay. Basically the code will now be tthe same linQ everyone cames with. With correct name on field, properties.

Comment: Even if using the correct datastructure was no the main part of the question, it was the main issue. Adressing it is more than a comment to me.